# Css3 toggle switch not posting on email contact form PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

This switch is part of a form, I can't get this element to be posted by the PHP into email, It seems to be not picking up the checked with the data-on="Yes" data-off="No" attribute of the switch.

HTML

```
<form class="booking-form" name="bookchalet" action="booking_form.php"  method="post"> 
    <div id="switchbox">
        <div class="switch">
            <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox"/>
            <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="switch">
            <input id="cmn-toggle-4" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round-flat" type="checkbox"/>
            <label for="cmn-toggle-4"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="switch">
            <input id="cmn-toggle-7" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-yes-no" name="apartment" type="checkbox"/>
            <label for="cmn-toggle-7"  data-on="Yes" data-off="No" ></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>   
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    if ($_POST["submit"]){
        $apartment = $_POST['apartment'];
        $submit = $_POST['submit'];
        $to = 'myemail@email.com';
        $headers = 'From: website' . "\r\n";
        $subject =  'FORM: '.$submit. "\r\n";
        $message =  ' Booking Details: '.$submit.', With apartment?:'.$apartment.."\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
        echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
        $url = 'index.html';
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';  
    }
    }
?>
```

I have taken out other elements of the form as it was pretty long and they were posting to email correctly.

Comment: Many Thanks @TinyGiant for helping, any idea on how I can resolve the issue?

Comment: I removed this element as i could not find a solution, wish someone would have been able to tell me why it was unanswerable, even it it was just that it isn't possible

Answer (score 1):

In your .php code I do not see any connection to your database and/or an insertion statement. . . Code that would look like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
 VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Using this concept you should be able to input your data and achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: the form is not set up to attach to a database, just to email the details directly

Comment: i have clarified the question above